# pandas distribution table grouped by all columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a **pandas** data frame like the following, I want to aggregate and get distribution for each unique record:

```
      col1   col2    col3  
0       1      3       0  
1       1      2       0  
2       1      2       0  
3       1      5       1  
4       1      3       1  
5       1      5       0
```

I would like to get the get a data frame like the following:

```
       col1   col2    col3   distribution
0       1      3       0         0.166
1       1      3       1         0.166
2       1      2       0         0.333
3       1      5       1         0.166
4       1      5       0         0.166
```

is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: what is your distribution function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html), create new column `distribution` with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) and divide it by [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3'])['col1'].count().reset_index(name='distribution')
df['distribution'] = df['distribution'] / df['distribution'].sum()
print df
   col1  col2  col3  distribution
0     1     2     0      0.333333
1     1     3     0      0.166667
2     1     3     1      0.166667
3     1     5     0      0.166667
4     1     5     1      0.166667
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the dataframe containing the data is called `df`, iterate through each row (which will return the row as a series), compute the distribution (assuming standard deviation here) and attach a new column at the end. For example:

```
distribution = list()
for row in df.iterrows():
  distribution.append(row[1].std())
df['distribution'] = distribution
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use apply and specify it along the correct axis. In this example, I find the mean of each row, but you can use your distribution function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], columns=['c1','c2','c3'])

df
   c1  c2  c3
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9

df.loc[:, 'row_mean'] = df.apply(np.mean, axis=1)

df
   c1  c2  c3  row_mean
0   1   2   3         2
1   4   5   6         5
2   7   8   9         8
```

Comment: sorry if it wasn't clear I want the mean not across each row, but the frequency of each unique record by grouping all columns, so each unique combination of c1, c2, c3, in my example 1, 2, 0 occurs twice and divide that by total number of rows